# Visualforce as Word doc editable on mobile

Tags: visualforce, mobile

Is there a way to make a visualforce page that is rendered as a Word document editable on mobile? If not, is there some other format that would work for this?

Comment: VF pages are markups and are used to render UI, and that those will be editable only by admins/developers. Can you elaborate what is your use case here? In its current form its not very clear as what are you trying to achieve. I will recommend that you take a look on [how to ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/256591/edit) with details for someone to be able to help.

Comment: you could create a Rich text field type.... you have some features from word. I am not sure how it will work in a mobile environment

Answer (score 2):

The **only** format that Salesforce can render Visualforce to other than its native text or HTML is PDF (using the `renderAs` attribute). Changing the MIME type or filename extension of a Visualforce page does not change its actual data type, only the type it's claiming to be. The Visualforce runtime cannot generate Microsoft Office files.

The behavior of client software, such as Microsoft Word and Excel, when opening a file claiming to be `.doc` or `.xls` but actually containing HTML markup, may vary significantly from version to version and from operating system to operating system. Because you're not rendering the actual target format, you typically have little to no control over how the file is ingested and presented by the software. This goes double if you're using software other than Office that tries to be compatible with Office file formats!

I consider it unwise to rely on this behavior. If you truly need, e.g., Microsoft Office files, consider using one of the many AppExchange solutions that can render the genuine article based on your templates.

Note that this does not apply if your Visualforce page actually renders a correctly structured XML document in the desired target format. This is possible for some, but not all, formats - it basically has to be a text- or XML-based format that isn't a zipped bundle - but this is tricky to do and demands in-depth knowledge of the target format and software.

Comment: a [related post on .xls](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120935/visualforce-multiline-utf-8-csv) which occupied my attentions for quite some time that reinforces your point "..this is tricky to do ....

Comment: @cropredy That is a great example! Excel for Mac is really something else.